# Prove this function is surjective

Tags: functions

How can I prove this function is surjective?

$f(x,y)=|x|-|y|$ , $f:\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z} \rightarrow \Bbb{Z}$

What cases do I need to use? When $x,y\le0$, $x,y\ge0$, $x\le0$ and $y\ge 0$, $x\ge 0$ and $y\le 0$?

Thanks.

Comment: In order to ask whether a function is surjective or not you **must** give a domain and a codomain for the functions, i.e.: you must tell us the function is $\;f:A\to B\;$ and properly define the sets $\;A,B\;$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove this is surjective, you just need to let $t \in \Bbb Z$.  $t$ is arbitrary, and could be positive, negative, or $0$.

If $t > 0$, then the ordered pair $(t, 0) \in \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ is being mapped to $t$ since $|t| - |0| = |t| = t$.

If $t = 0$, then the ordered pair $(0,0) \in \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ is being mapped to $t$ since $|0| - |0| = 0 - 0 = 0 = t$.

If $t < 0$, then the ordered pair $(0, t) \in \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ is being mapped to $t$ since $|0| - |t| = -|t| = t$.

So, in every case, we found an element being mapped to $t$, and since $t$ was arbitrary, the map is surjective.

Comment: Lucid explanation. Very nice. :) +1

Comment: @crash Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $k\in\mathbb Z$, if $k\geq 0$ 
$$k= |k|-|0|=f(k,0),$$
and if $k<0$, 
$$k=|0|-|k|=f(0,k).$$
Therefore it's surjective.